# One script causes another to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, conflict

I have a problem with a vertical scroll page where I'm using (intending to, that is) two nested quickscroll functions.

This is how it's supposed to look: [image] - just remove the scrollbar in your mind. I'm just using

```
overflow:scroll
```

here to manually check on things.

Since JS isn't my forte (I have only very basic knowledge of it), I just got a piece of code that worked similarly, reverse engineered it by removing as much as I could from the HTML and CSS until I was left with the bare function, and plugged it into my own page in terms of the needed HTML and CSS as well as the  code. I'm not using anything proprietary and I'm including author links, hoping that I'm on the safe side there (?)

So, the main scroll is a vertical one and inside one of the vertical sections I'm using this 'reverse engineered' horizontal quickscroll code.

The new (nested) script cancels out the main one. Any ideas how to fix this?

The main (vertical scroll)  is the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

            /* I added this to hide the menu during scroll and I'm mighty proud of myself! :) */
            $('.menu').addClass('hide');
    $('.book_arrow').addClass('hide');

    current = $(this);

    $('body').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 2600, function(){
        $('.menu').removeClass('hide');
        $('.book_arrow').removeClass('hide');
    });     

    return false;
});



});

</script>
```

It comes with these two linked files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
```

The conflicting code is a bit longer:

```
    <script>
  // initialize scrollable and return the programming API
  var api = $("#scroll").scrollable({
  items: '#tools'

  // use the navigator plugin
  }).navigator().data("scrollable");


  // this callback does the special handling of our "intro page"
  api.onBeforeSeek(function(e, i) {

  // when on the first item: hide the intro
  if (i) {
  $("#intro").fadeOut("slow");

  // dirty hack for IE7-. cannot explain
  if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8) {
                            $("#intro").hide();
                                }

                                    // otherwise show the intro
                                    } else {
                                $("#intro").fadeIn(1000);
                                    }

                                    // toggle activity for the intro thumbnail
                                    $("#t0").toggleClass("active", i == 0);
                                        });

                                        // a dedicated click event for the intro thumbnail
                                        $("#t0").click(function() {

                                    // seek to the beginning (the hidden first item)
                                    $("#scroll").scrollable().begin();

                                        });

</script>
```

...and it links to this file:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Does it matter where in the HTML I place all these chunks? In isolation, both scripts are working.

I've read about a seemingly similar case [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?715913-2-separate-javascript-overriding-one-another) and I'm thinking that maybe in my case I'm also dealing with variables that are 'occupied' by one of the functions, but I'm not exactly sure what to change and where.

I'm absolutely positively looking forward to learning a major lesson from this problem! :)

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: That's an *ancient* version of jQuery, and jQuery Tools is essentially a dead project.

Comment: Oh wow, then I might need to look for a different version of that horizontal scroll thingy....

I'll try to create a jsfiddle. I think my problem there before was that I need images and I couldn't just upload them in jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I just made a jsfiddle.

It looks pretty messed up because the images aren't there, but I think it shows the problem. 

Surprizingly, the horizontal quickscroll in section 2 works, at least it skips to the individual page/box. But the scrolling is suposed to be smooth.

http://jsfiddle.net/b8Dnv/1/

Sorry for my totally messy CSS and everything. I'm pretty new to this. All I can say is that the page looks rather nice in my browsers already. Just the scrolling scripts don't work together.

Comment: Note: the jsfiddle has different content. Instead of that poetry section up on the screenshot I inserted the html of that quickscroll function I'm intending to use there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Amdx/1386/ here's a simpler jsfiddle of a similar effect. I have nested mousewheel quickscroll effects, but here, they fire together. What I'm trying to achieve is that the mousecursor 'locks' the outer scroll in place, selecting the inner scroll. 

Gee, it's hard to describe these things! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that it doesn't cause the Stack to Overflow, I'll add some more (my solution) to my journey. Maybe it helps posterity to follow my learning curve...

I was able to get the nested quick scroll (as I call it) to work properly. Still a rookie in JS, I played around with that bit of script I had gotten and modified - the one that worked vertically - and stuffed the other, similar, script for the (inner) horizontal scroll into that first script! YAY! It worked. Here's how the final script looks:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.panel').click(function () {
    $('.book_arrow').fadeOut();
            ## which prevents the vertical page flying past a lot of nav during scroll down ##

    $('.fluid_centerbox').addClass('hide');
    $('.fluid_centerbox').fadeOut();
            ## which makes the scroll smooth cause what's {display:none;} isn't going to be recalculated           
            and also lets the viewer appreciate the background images during scroll. the 'hide' is 
            instant and the .fadeOut is animated. Don't ask me why it worked best in this order! ##

    current = $(this);

    $('body').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 2600, function(){
        $('.book_arrow').fadeIn();
        $('.fluid_centerbox').fadeIn(), 40000;

    });     

    return false;
});

$('a.panell').click(function () {
    current = $(this);
    $('.long_wrap').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 2600, function(){
    });     

    return false;
    });
## the panell is not a typo but a way to distinguish both scroll button types ##
});

</script>
```

And while I'm posting this, I see that in the inner quick scroll, there's an empty

```
function(){});
```

Maybe later I'll try to get rid of it, if possible.